# hex to decimal conversion in java

Tags: android

I want to ask how can i convert from hex to decimal in Java ?
I tried using parseInt by getting the number from the user in an edit text and view the result in a text view after splitting the long spaced number but its not working 
any ideas ?

```
 String s=et.getText().toString();
String[] F=s.split(" ");
String last=F[F.length-1] ; 
int i=Integer.parseInt(last, 16);

tv1.setText(i);
```

Comment: "its not working"... Do you get an error? If yes, what error do you get? At compile time or at run-time? In which line of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close... just make sure to convert `i` to a string like this:

```
tv1.setText(i + "");
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: glad to hear it! don't forget to mark as correct :) have a great day!